# DWR : Failed to load resource: resources/dwr/call/plaincall/__System.generateId.dwr

Tags: java, spring, dwr

my purpose is to execute a simple dwr function that returns a string.

Spring version `4.3.5.RELEASE`
Spring security version `4.1.4.RELEASE`
dwr version `3.0.0-RELEASE.`

I'm using Java based config. I have correctly generated all of the 3 necessaries JS files:

```
engine.js
util.js
interface/myDwr.js
```

I can see the 3 generated files in the browser when the application runs locally.

The problem appears when i try to execute a very simple function marked as `@RemoteMethod` in the class marked as `@RemoteProxy(name="ajaxController")`

All i get from the browser is:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not 
 Allowed)  resources/dwr/call/plaincall/__System.generateId.dwr
```

In Debug mode i can see that my @RemoteMethod is not getting called.

The method is called testDWR:

```
@RemoteProxy(name="ajaxController")
public class DWRFunctions {
    @RemoteMethod
    public String testDWR(String s) {
        return "Hello Mr/Mrs "+s;
    }
}
```

The Javascript function that calls it is:

```
 function testDWR() {
    ajaxController.testDWR("Franklin", function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

The javascript is triggered by a simple html button:

```
<button onclick="testDWR()">TEST DWR</button>
```